# Grails 2.3.11 - Object failing to persist

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to modify some entities in a service using Grails 2.3.11.  I have stripped down to this code:

```
void updateCompanyType(CompanyType type, Map properties) {
    def role = properties.role?.id ==~ /\d+/ ? Role.get(properties.role.id) : null

    role.name = "Super New Name"
    role.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

    if (type.role != role) {
        type.role = role
    }

    type.name = properties.name
    type.save(failOnError: true)
}
```

Type successfully updates, but the role does not.  Any insight into why?  I know that inside a service call, I'm in a transaction, so I've tried this both with and without the explicit save calls, and that seems to make no difference.

Partial look at the Role class:

```
class Role implements Comparable {

  Integer id
  String name
  String code
  RoleType roleType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by setting

> version true

on my Role domain object in the mapping section.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
def role = properties.role?.id ==~ /\d+/ ? Role.get(properties.role.id) : null
```

into

```
def role = properties.role?.id ==~ /\d+/ ? Role.get(properties.role.id) : new Role()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it.  It's definitely getting the object and setting the attribute.  I can see that in the debugger.  It's just not persisting.

Comment: I should add that, as I said, this is stripped-down code, so the null value actually ends up pushing it into another block where it instantiates a new Role when the full code is present.

Comment: I would put a break point on the line where you have role.save and see if you have any specific domain errors by simply calling role.errors

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That's not something I was familiar with.  I tried it and it shows no errors either before or after the save call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Spring Security Role object, have you extended it to add "name" to the object? and if so, did you define it in the extended object as "def name" or "String name"?

Either way, if you declare a property inside a domain class as "def" or "private" it does not persist it to the database, even though when you look at it in the debugger, it will have the property and the value. Also, if you are using the built in database schema generator utils and migrations, did it actually create a "name" column in the "role" table, or did you do that manually?

Would need to see what your domain class looks like for "Role"?

Comment: No, it's a completely independent Role class.  All of the attributes are defined with named types.  Thing is, it's seemingly not an issue with the class, as I can actually change an attribute on type.role and it will persist, but if I change any attributes on the role that I retrieve via get/read/find in that method, the changes on it won't persist.

Comment: I added a snippet of the Role class to the original post.